# setDefaultsOnInsert not working with upsert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, typegoose

I am using typegoose to create a schema, where I am defining the **default** field for a property. This means that if I don't set a value for that field in the setQuery, it should use that default value in the schema while inserting.

This does not work with `updateOne` method where I set options as `{upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true}`

While, if I use `create`, the defaults are set correctly.

Mongoose: 5.7.14
MongoDB: 3.2.20
Node: 8
Typescript: 3.8.3
Typegoose: 5.9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it wasn't working was because I was explicitly mentioning the field value as `undefined` .

Eg.

```
const updatePayload = {
id: "123",
dob: someObject.dateOfBirth
}
```

`someObject.dateOfBirth` was resulting to undefined. The defaults would have worked if I didn't have the `dob` key in the update payload.